# Using NestJS and Mongoose, why isn't my updateOne method working to update a user's name by ID?

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, crud

In the `update` method of my NestJS `UserService`, I'm using `updateOne` to update a user's name by their ID. However, the update doesn't seem to be working properly. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the relevant code:

```
async update(id: ObjectId, updateUserDto: UpdateUserDto) {
  return await this.userModel.updateOne({
    _id: id,
    name: {
      firstName: updateUserDto.name.firstName,
      lastName: updateUserDto.name.lastName,
    },
  });
}
```

Thanks for helping me out!

When I call this method and pass in a user ID and a UpdateUserDto object containing a new first name and/or last name, I expect the user's name to be updated in the database. However, when I check the database after calling the update method, the name hasn't changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-updateOne) the correct function call should have 2 arguments: 1st for filter, 2nd for updated fields.

```
async update(id: ObjectId, updateUserDto: UpdateUserDto) {
  return await this.userModel.updateOne({_id: id,}, {
    name: {
      firstName: updateUserDto.name.firstName,
      lastName: updateUserDto.name.lastName,
    },
  });
}
```